# Magento: Admin receive email on new order

Tags: php, magento

Does anyone know if administrators of a magento store receive an email when a new order is created? If so, where/how do I edit it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Log in into admin area, then go to "system -> configuration" menu. Within the Sales section: click the Sales Emails and select the first section Orders. Enter your admin e-mail in the field “Send Order Email Copy To”.

From the top of my head, but it's some configuration issue (no programming required).

Comment: By the way, this option is not set by default.

Comment: Seems broken on some Magento versions. 2.2.4, 2.2.5 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16203