# How to get order details after an order placed using observer

Tags: magento

I would like to get the order details using **observer**  ,

Once i get the order it will sent order details to my test email , but i can not able to get the order details.

please check the code which i tried to get the order details,  Can someone let me know how can i get the order details , thanks.

```
public function postdata($observer) {
    $to = 'testmail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Mail after Sale order place.';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $message = 'This is my first Magento Observer After Sale order place';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $order_message =   $order;
    foreach($order as $ok => $ov) {
        $order_message .= $ok. " => " .$ov;
    }
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please specify which event your using?

Comment: Hi arshad i am using sales_order_place_after

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Magento to send you a copy of the order confirmation email that gets sent to the customer. If that is sufficient for your needs, [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068598/1737136) will do the trick.

Comment: Nope i am not sending only the order data , The thing is i am adding an custome checkbox in checkout page , when customer click the checkbox  the mail need to sent to my custome id with order details and with wheather the checkbox is clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sale_order_save_after` event to get the order details after place the order.